# About type definition of Hyperledger Fabric SDK for node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, hyperledger-fabric, type-definition

Sorry for the machine translation

Is type ByteBuffer in the type definition file index.d.ts of @ types / fabric-client the same as Buffer?

[index.d.ts link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/fabric-client/index.d.ts)

Please tell me if you have any other good inquiries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, a ByteBuffer and Buffer are different objects.  The Buffer is native to node.js and ByteBuffer is an npm package (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/bytebuffer).  For example, see https://github.com/dcodeIO/ByteBuffer.js/issues/1 for converting a ByteBuffer to Buffer.